# Extracting information from drawings

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, drawing

I've identified and extracted the coordinates of the instruments from the drawing using template matching( OpenCV, python). Now I need to extract the lines and associations between the instruments(which instrument is connected to what).Even if I'm able to find half the connections, it will be great. But I can't find a way to it. Please help..

[Example image with detected instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owEmo.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

This is already pretty good. I suggest using Hough line detection to first detect all line segments in the image that are not part of the instrument borders. These lines can then be grouped as:

1. Connected directly to two instruments.
2. Connected to one instrument and a perpendicular line
3. Other

You can detect the first category easily, but will need some work for the second. The third will have to be handled as special cases.

Make sure that the high level model you have defined to represent instruments supports making the connections that are available.